# USB issues with macbook pro and audio interface

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, usb

Hi I have this very odd issue with a late 2013 retina 15" MBP (ME294LL/A) 16gb 2.3ghz i7

I have an apogee symphony desktop audio interface connected via USB.

It was working fine for like 6 months when I got the apogee (I bought the laptop used) and then suddenly while recording in Logic Pro X the audio interface just stops transmitting audio. It doesn't disconnect from the computer though, it still shows at connected, but there is no audio. There's also no audio if I try to listen to anything else (youtube, spotify etc.)

When I switch to laptop speakers on the spot, the audio plays. Then I switch back to apogee and it doesn't work. Only some combo of restarting the interface unit itself and/or the computer makes it work again. But it only works for a few minutes before disconnecting.

The same issue happens if I don't even use Logic and just listen to youtube or something. Again, the device itself (and it's control software) do not disconnect, just no audio.

I've contacted the manufacturer and we spent a week trying different things. They thought it was the unit so they sent me a new unit. The same issue happens with the new unit.

I've tried resetting nvram, smc etc., we've gone through all the steps with apogee tech as far as reinstalling the software. I've even tried doing a fresh install of OSX with no data being kept.

The only other usb device to test is an android phone and it connects fine and transfers data. No other USB devices are available to test.

I did an apple hardware test and it passed.

The problem happens in both usb ports.

Does anyone have any advice. Can this be due to a bad usb controller chip? It seems unlike to be at the port, as the device connects, and same issue with both ports happens.

I'm thinking maybe it needs a new logic board? Or can I take it to microcenter or something and have them replace just the usb controller chip?

It's so perpelxing what the problem could be! Any advice/insight would be helpful thanks

Comment: What version of macOS? Did you recently do a macOS version update, or install an intermediary Security update?

Comment: Did you try, in Audio Midi Setup, changing the sample rate? [from any to any & back again if you need it for your project, though not with Logic running.] It was an issue at one point, which for me eventually just went away again. No idea what caused it.

Comment: @IconDaemon it's been on big sur for the last 6 months. no updates were done. as stated above issue only started a few weeks ago. no other system things were changed, either on apogee or osx or anything.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried every permutation of closing this or that, restarting this or that, pluggin usb out and in with logic open with it closed etc. etc. etc. I must have tried that too but just to be safe I'll try it again.

Comment: I assumed you probably had, but for me it used to happen so often it became reflex. I use an old Line6 UX2 still on Mojave [because I still like to be able to use my Amp Farm & Variax software, neither of which will work with Catalina or newer] I think it was around the Sierras it used to happen, but eventually just went away, never to return. I do wish you luck :)